# AssertionError: missing sha1, make sure sjcl is configured correctly

Tags: php, blockchain, blockchain.info-api

I have implement Blockchain Wallet API in my API. It has features like create wallet, send, received bitcoion, etc. working fine with local computer.

But same code will move on my live server it'll give error as below
error:

> AssertionError: missing sha1, make sure sjcl is configured correctly
>
> at Object.stretchPassword (/usr/lib/node_modules/blockchain-wallet-service/node_modules/blockchain-wallet-client-prebuilt/src/wallet-crypto.js:328:3)
>
> at encryptDataWithPassword (/usr/lib/node_modules/blockchain-wallet-service/node_modules/blockchain-wallet-client-prebuilt/src/wallet-crypto.js:275:28)
>
> at Object.encryptWallet (/usr/lib/node_modules/blockchain-wallet-service/node_modules/blockchain-wallet-client-prebuilt/src/wallet-crypto.js:136:14)
>
> at insertWallet (/usr/lib/node_modules/blockchain-wallet-service/src/create.js:60:39)
>
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

Also I have setup node, npm and blockchain wallet service on my server successfully.

Any one idea please let me know why it'll not work.

Comment: did you get this working?